# How to publish in Visual Studio .NET core app for linux-musl-x64 (Alpine Linux)?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, alpine-linux

How do I publish my app for Alpine Linux, which is targeted with `linux-musl-x64` runtime?
When I create a publish profile, I don't have the option to select this runtime.
I have two options: `linux-x64` and `linux-arm` for Linux deployment, nothing else.

[image: Publish profile]

What and where, do I need to modify to add a new target runtime?

Comment: What happens if you'll do that from command line using `dotnet publish`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski To be honest, I tried it after seeing your comment (`dotnet build --runtime linux-musl-x64`). The build was successful. Still, wondering about the UI in Visual Studio.

Comment: What I did, I manually edited my `FolderProfile.pubxml` and changed it to: `<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-musl-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` and this works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to add my custom runtime, I found the Visual Studio profile file in my project folder (FolderProfile.pubxml in my case) and edited the `RuntimeIdentifier` element:
`<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-musl-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

this seems to have worked.
[image]

Other workaround is to run the command in command prompt:
`dotnet build --runtime linux-musl-x64`

Also worth reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

> You can see the list of supported RIDs and the RID graph in the
> runtime.json file, which is located at the dotnet/runtime repository.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Windows! Please use Void-Linux or Alpine and you should prompt `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-musl-x64 -p:StaticLink=true --self-contained=true` Why not use Windows because Windows doesn't have musl-libc base system that's why you need use Void-Linux or Alpine. Musl-libc base system is very required and important for statical mode without worrying loaded so files.

If you get error while including statical libraries then you should copy `""clang" ......"` and past to new line and replace `"clang"` with `"x86_64-linux-musl-gcc -static"` and find `-lrt` you want add `-l(library-package)` then you need remove `-pie` until  musl-gcc  generates new executable of dotnet native aot executable.
You need make non-stripping of executable. `strip -S bin/Release/net7.0/linux-musl-x64/native/YOUR-OUTPUT-EXECUTABLE`.
Then you can check out `ldd bin/Release/net7.0/linux-musl-x64/native/YOUR-OUTPUT-EXECUTABLE`
It looks simple statical single executable from Dotnet + musl version. It is really easy to compile and release your Dotnet native aot end executable.

Enjoy your happy compiling and happy releasing